# jqGrid how to get selected text from a dropdown cell

Tags: jqgrid

Here is the `colModel` for a cell that displays dropdown list. I am trying to get selected text in the dropdown

```js
{name:'pdInstanceType', edittype:'select', formatter:'select', 
editable:true, editoptions:{value:"1:Test1;2:Test2"}}
```

The below code gives me the selected value(1 or 2) instead of text (Test1 or Test2)

```js
jQuery("#tableId").jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'pdInstanceType');
```

Is there a way to get the selected text? Greatly appreciate any inputs!

Comment: It's important to know: which editing mode you use? Where (in which callback or event handler) you try to get the value?

Comment: I am using row editing using `jQuery("#tableId").editRow(rowId);`. I need to get the text in two different places - loadComplete and on change event of the dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone else looking at a similar problem, here is how I was able to get the selected text of a drop down list in a jqGrid Cell.

```
var dropdown = jQuery('#' + rowId + 'pdInstanceType')[0];
var selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];
var selectedText = selectedOption.text;
```

Comment: on which callback event you are doing it?

Comment: try **$('#'+rowId+'pdInstanceType'+'option:selected').text()**

Comment: Thanks....its working fine.... but 4.6.0 version need to add '_'  like            var dropdown = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_pdInstanceType')[0];

Answer (score 1):

Same code as [RRK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729961/rrk) just a little shorter using all [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (v1.8.2):

```
var stringVal = $('#' + rowId + 'pdInstanceType').val(); // (Returns string)
```